# win performance monitor: monitor service by using "command line" instead of "name"

Tags: performance, monitor

I need to track a process by using performance monitor , and this is pretty simple
The problem is that I have more processes with the same name and basically i don't know which one i need
For example, take a look at the picture, i  have two sql server but let's say i want to track the first one , how can i do that?
From what i see , the only difference is the command line so ,  would be great if i could track the one i need by using cmd line instead of name.
is it possible?
any idea?

[img sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37sD8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the process name, there is also the process identification number (PID), which is unique for each process. It is listed in the task manager under the details tab.

Comment: yes, that's a good option but, i have a kind of automated test and , when it runs, i start to monitor performances . The problem is that PID is different every time :-(